# Shopify how to send invited email for existing custoemer?

Tags: shopify-app

guys. I am new to shopify development. now I am developing shopify private app through API. When I through API to create new customer with send_invited_email=true, it works perfectly. However, when I try to send invited email for existing customers, send_invited_email=true cannot work. If anyone has idea? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please show some code, things you've tried and research you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "send_email_welcome": true and you will get result.

Thanks